# Unpacking ActiveRecord binary blob to hex string drops escape characters ("%25" converted to "%")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Ruby-on-Rails app that accepts a binary file upload, stores it as an ActiveRecord object in a local database, and passes a hex equivalent of the binary blob to a back-end web service for processing.  This usually works great.

Two days ago, I ran into a problem with a file containing the hex sequence `\x25\x32\x35`, `%25` in ASCII.  The binary representation of the file was stored properly in the database but the hex string representation of the file that resulted from

```
sample.binary.unpack('H*').to_s
```

was incorrect.  After investigating, I found that those three bytes were converted to hex string `25`, the representation for `%`. It should have been `253235`, the representation for `%25`

It makes sense for Ruby or Rails or ActiveRecord to do this. `%25` is the proper URL-encoded value for `%`.  However, I need to turn off this optimization or validation or whatever it is.  I need `blob.unpack('H*')` to include a hex equivelant for every byte of the blob.

One (inefficient) way to solve this is to store a hex representation of the file in the database.  Grabbing the file directly from the HTTP POST request works fine:

```
params[:sample].read.unpack('H*').to_s
```

That stores the full `253235`.  Something about the roundtrip to the database (sqlite) or the HTTPClient post from the front-end web service to the back-end web service (hosted within WEBrick) is causing the loss of fidelity.

Eager to hear any ideas, willing to try whatever to test out suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with rails and it's sqlite adapter:

There is a bug filed here in the old rails system (with patch):
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5040

And a new bug filed here in the new rails issue tracking system:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2407

Any string that contains '%00' will be mangled when converting to binary and back.  A binary that contains the string '%25' will be converted to '%' which is what you are seeing.